# Can somebody help my enlarge the EFI Partition?

Tags: partitioning, efi

These are my current partitions. How do I move 500 MB from C: or F: to the EFI?

[image]

Comment: You can follow my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1712902/718047) regarding enlarging a partition posted today, as the process would be almost identical

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I clone a Windows 10 disk onto a larger disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/1712900/how-can-i-clone-a-windows-10-disk-onto-a-larger-disk)

Comment: Probably easier to just delete it and create a new one towards the end of the drive.

Comment: @DanielB your half-advice could easily render someones system unbootable if he doesn't know what he is doing.