# OSMC doesn't update due to no free space on boot partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, raspberry-pi, osmc

- I have OSMC on Raspberry Pi 3b
- and a 16 GB SD card
- the most space on this card is free
- ... except of boot partition
- `apt-get dist-upgrade` fails due to lack of free space on boot partition
- `apt-get autoremove` didn't find anything to remove

What would you do to get the things done?

P.S. After a reboot and repeated `apt-get dist-upgrade` execution the updater suddenly found that it should upgrade ... everything. Except vmlinuz kernel. As a result, OSMC boots and can watch videos, but I cannot log on over SSH anymore. **Update** SSH was just updated to stronger encryption. I had to get a new version of PuTTY.

**Update**

Using Win32DiskImager I restored the 16GB card backup to a 32GB card, checked that it boots, then inserted it into PC again and using Minitool Partition Wizard 7 performed two operations:

- Moved the last and largest 15GB partition (number 4) for 220 MB towards the end of SD card (Minitool Partition Wizard couldn't change ext4 partition size, so I only moved it as it is)
- and increased the boot partition (number 3) to 220 MB, making it 300 MB

After that I tried to boot and OSMC went into eternal boot loop with berry screen and suggestion to press Shift for recovery.

NOOBS recovery isn't actually a recovery, but is able only to overwrite everything on the card with initial OSMC installation.

So I owerwrote the garbled card contents with my backup. Now I am waiting for another variants to expand the boot partition.

Comment: Pull the SD out and resize the partitions on a PC, e.g. with gparted.

Comment: @mashuptwice: it ended in an eternal boot loop then (see the updated question).

Comment: Well, you should use *nix tools like gparted for working on linux partitions. [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) could be used as a bootable OS if you don't have a PC running Linux.

Comment: You can of course "wait for another variant", but the principle will stay the same, only the tools involved will be different. For resizing, check [this guide I wrote a while ago](https://superuser.com/a/1712902/718047). Ignore the part about cloning and modify the instructions to be relevant for your boot partition.