# PC wont turn on

Tags: windows, boot, power-supply

My desktop PC doesnt't turn on after I shut it down by using the power switch. If I don't use power switch to turn off the PC, it will turn on properly.

Also, when I try to turn it on the mouse lights up but the fans don't spin and there are no lights illuminated on the front of the computer.

To test this problem I removed the power cable 3-4 times for 10-20 seconds, and sometimes by doing this the fans start spinning and the light on the front of the PC turns on. There is no display for 5 seconds, then the manufacturer name appears, and the PC starts beeping every 2-3 seconds.

I suspect this is because of the HDD not being properly connected. After some time a black screen or Windows logo appears with no dots spinning. After this I restart the system and the same problem persists.

In another test I hit the case which moves the wire and HDD so it is detected and the result is that the system boots smoothly.

Also, the hibernate function fails to load when I do that, and all my work is lost. This process eats up nearly 30 min of my day.

thanks @Kalamalka Kid for rephrasing.. i have very little experiences with these technical things

Comment: You seem to have some hardware problems. Maybe your power supply is glitching. I suggest using a professional, rather than trying it yourself.

Comment: How many beeps? And what is the brand/model pc?

Comment: @Mastaxx the beeps continue every 3-4 sec until i shake the PC a little and by chance it stops i think by shking.. the SATA cable for HDD moves and the system recognizes the HDD.. sometime the HDD becomes lose when the PC is working.. same thing.. all the functionalities work but it beeps and it is not shown in file explorer.. when i shake the system prompt- "NEW VOLUME(D)(E)(F)".. the pc is custom build i can't understand what you mean by brand/model.. the motherboard is ASROCK H110M-DGS

Answer (score 1):

> There is no display for 5 sec then the manufacturer name pops up and the PC starts beeping every 2-3 secs..

The beep code pattern is the first step to investigate.  Sometimes it's as straight forward as reseating the GPU or RAM modules.

The beeps are diagnostic beep codes that are part of the power-on self test (POST).  There are a variety of hardware "things" that can trigger these beep codes, such as the CPU, GPU or a RAM module(s) being poorly seated/failing/missing, power supply issues, etc.  Motherboard/computer manufacturers typically include the beep codes and their descriptions in the manual.

One quick thing you can try is to unplug the power cable (as you've already done) and press the power button a few times while the computer is off and unplugged.  This discharges the capacitors.  Sometimes this can fix wonky boot issues.

However, I would advise against "hitting the case" as a troubleshooting method.  This can knock other things/cables loose and you might end up causing a completetly new issue without realizing it.  In addition, internal HDD's aren't (usuallly) as robust as laptop HDDs in terms of tolerating impacts.

I think [Kalamalka Kid](https://superuser.com/users/598567/kalamalka-kid) is on the right track and I agree that you should try using a different SATA cable and/or SATA port on the motherboard.

Since you're zeroing in on the HDD, try unplugging the HDD completely (unplug the SATA cable from the motherboard-side, and unplug the power cable from the hard drive) and see if the computer still beeps or has trouble getting to the point where it says it can't find a boot device or tries booting from the network (PXE boot) etc.

- If you're still hearing beep codes with the HDD unplugged, that still doesn't guarantee that the HDD is without issues; an intermittenly failing HDD (that *isn't* triggering POST beep codes) ***and*** poorly seated RAM (that *is* triggering POST beep codes) can exist simultaneously.  If you have the means, test the HDD using a different computer.

You can use a tool like [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/download/#CrystalDiskInfo) to see if the drive is reporting any SMART errors (that is, if/when you can boot into Windows).  If you do see SMART errors, it might be time to replace the HDD.

Comment: i dont have extra SATA ports availaible.. they seem unresponsive.. the only 2 SATA port are being used for my SSD and the HDD.. also.. the beeping noice is perfectly synced with a viberation sound like the disk is spinning.. disk spins and right after then.. beep sound.. then disk spins the beep.. somethimes the beep delays but overall it is synced.. i conclude with that that the HDD is the culprit.. and this is not even the main problem.. the main problem is.. why the PC doen't turn on when i press power button.. this nplgging and repluging takes time..

Comment: also.. i dont hit it too hard.. just little shake type push.. is it bad??

Comment: The question stated that "the PC starts beeping" and not "the HDD starts beeping" so I interpreted that as coming from the motherboard.  The "beeps" from the hard drive are probably the HDD head(s) constantly resetting position - an indication that the HDD is likely malfunctioning.  At this point I would encourage you to take the computer to a local repair shop for diagnosis.  They will have the tools and resources to run the necessary tests in order to diagnose the issues, which may be 2x unrelated issues.  And yes, impacting a HDD as a troubleshooting method is poor form.

Comment: here.. most of the repair shops are not very well trained.. they just say that the BIOS is currupt or the HDD is currupted you have to buy a new one.. no diagnostics.. no tools.. nothing.. they just order replacement for the new part and hand us the long bill.. thats why i was trying to first check if i could do it with some help.. also.. when you advised to remove HDD and boot.. the display got affected and there was only a black screen.. then i reinstalled the CMOS 2-3 times and then the display came..

Comment: now.. the HDD dont beep as i placed it carefully in the correct slot firmly.. but the currupted BIOs problem is still there.. as soon as the machine looses power.. the BIOS currupts and it wont turn on again.. but now.. it starts after one try of taking power cable out and puting it back in.. also.. the hibernate feature stared working.. now.. there is just one problem.. that the PC doesn't start in one try.. it boots.. manufacturer logo.. the the CMOS screen appears.. that press F1 to continue or F2/DEL to enter boot menu.. i press F1 and it boot smoothly..is there a fix for power cable thing

Comment: There's little troubleshooting  you can do moving forward without tools or spare parts.  Power supply testers can vary in cost, but that's the first thing I would test with your computer.  I would also test the HDD on a different computer.  If the PSU tested OK, I would still try installing a new PSU to see if that made a difference.  The issues you're having don't present as straight foward problems.  I wouldn't normally update the BIOS with such a flaky system.  Honestly, you might be looking at replacing one or more components.  Sometimes replacing parts is just part of the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue seems to be hardware related there are a few issues that come to mind (bad cable, loose connection, failing HDD). I would suggest a few things to troubleshoot your problem:

## Test the cables

Trying out some new cables for your HDD could help since physically hitting the case to jiggle the wire seems to give you a positive result.

If your HDD is external it should be easy to replace the cable to test this, however if it is an internal HDD, you will need to open up the case and replace the SATA cable that connects to the motherboard.

If replacing the SATA cable that connects to the motherboard does not work, you can try connecting to another SATA port on the motherboard to test if the issue is with the SATA port.

## Clone your OS

If your issue persists after all of this it might be indicative of a failing HDD, in which case your best option is to [clone your data](https://superuser.com/questions/1712900/how-can-i-clone-a-windows-10-disk-onto-a-larger-disk) onto a new drive and test again.

Comment: the HDD is internal.. and i cant switch SATA ports.. i have only two and both are occupied.. when i switch them.. the SSD is always recognised no matter what port.. just the HDD is troublesome..